# Как при помощи CSS менять при нажатии цвет?

Tags: css

Есть такая верстка:

```
<div class="first-div">
 <div>
   
 </div>
</div>
```

Элемент `div` находится во внешнем `<div class="first-div">`. Как при нажатии на: `<div class="first-div">` менять стиль внутреннего `div`, а при ещё одном нажатии откатывать назад? Желательно с использованием только css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В CSS3 клик можно обрабатывать благодаря вот такому "костылю" с чекбоксом:

```css
.first-div {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.first-div > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}

input:checked ~ div {
    border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
 <label for="toggle"></label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
 <div>

 </div>
</div>
```

То есть Вы создаёте чекбокс и скрываете его. Создаёте label для этого чекбокса и с помощью позиционирования накладываете label на весь внешний блок. Получается, что вроде как Вы кликаете по блоку, но на самом деле по label. И чекбокс меняет свою активность.

А уже стили внутреннего блока вы ставите в зависимость от того, активен чекбокс или нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Интересное решение.

Comment: С помощью такой штуки (правда, не чекбокс, а радиобаттон), можно делать, например, фотогалерею на чистом css, безо всякого js

Comment: @humster_spb и попутно наплевать на семантику, доступность и написать тяжко поддерживаемый код )

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, а что не так здесь с семантикой и доступностью?

Comment: @humster_spb элементы радиобаттон, лейбл и прочие — это элементы для форм, а не для фотогалереи.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, что мешает обернуть фотогалерею в теги <form></form>, если это так принципиально?

Comment: @humster_spb если птицу назвать самолетом, то это мало что поменяет.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, идею фотогалереи на радиобатонах придумал не я - этому учат, например, в htmlacademy. Ну, расскажите этим ребятам про "наплевать на семантику, доступность и написать тяжко поддерживаемый код" :) Уверен, они над Вами весело посмеются.

Comment: @humster_spb что сказать, надо будет написать Вадиму.

Answer (score 3):

Можно задать цвет в .first-div через color (напр. color: red), а в дочернем использовать переменную current-color (background: currentColor), вот пример - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpLRar

```css
.first-div {
  color: yellow;
}

.first-div div {
  background: currentColor;
}

.first-div p {
  color: black;
}

.first-div:active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel aperiam illo fugiat inventore nostrum eligendi incidunt, velit doloribus corporis praesentium assumenda, harum ea quisquam accusamus soluta sit nesciunt sequi. Suscipit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Также если нужно именно toggle-поведение, то вместо div использовать label и checkbox с ним:

```css
#myCheckbox {
  display: none;
}

#myCheckbox:checked + .first-div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />
<label for="myCheckbox" class="first-div">
 <!-- your code -->
</label>
```

Comment: Тем не менее, это не совсем то, что спрашивал автор "а при ещё одном нажатии откатывать назад" - в Вашем примере работает не нажатие, а зажатие

Comment: тогда можно использовать :focus, либо вместо div использовать label + checkbox

Answer (score 1):

На чистом css я не вижу способа, как это можно реализовать (при наведении легко, а вот при нажатии уже хз)

Но можно простой строчкой на jquery это сделать: 
При нажатии на div - его дочернему div либо дается новый класс red, либо убирается, если он уже есть

```
<div class="first-div" onclick="$('.first-div > div').toggleClass('red');">
 <div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на css с использованием псевдокласса `:target`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#parent a[href="#parent"],
#parent a[href="#parentHidden"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

#parent a[href="#parent"] {
  display: block;
  color: #555;
}

#parent a[href="#parentHidden"] {
  display: none;
}

#parent .childDiv {
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#parent .childDiv:before {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}

#parent:target a[href="#parent"] {
  display: none;
}

#parent:target a[href="#parentHidden"] {
  display: block;
}

#parent:target .childDiv {
  display: block;
  color: #f00;
}

#parent:target .childDiv:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a href="#parent" tabindex="1">label</a>
  <a href="#parentHidden" tabindex="1">label hidden</a>

  <div class="childDiv">Child</div>
</div>
```